# Anyone know the frames per second that IOS apps run?

Tags: game-design, directx, ios, iphone, first-person-shooter

Anyone know the frame rate that iphones, ipads, and even android mobiles run?

Comment: maximum 60 frames per second

Comment: Thanks, if you dont mind, what do you think is a recommended fps rate for like an turn based rpg game, for mobile that is?

Comment: as much as you can get above 30

Comment: @raxvan No it's not. Especially on mobile devices! If I notice a game draining my battery while not providing anything in return (like superb graphics), it's gone faster than you're able to show any kind of "Do you really want to quit?" message. :)

Comment: It renders a frame every 16 milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know all those devices are able to show up to 60 fps, however, for mobile development you should think differently:

- You've tagged your question with 'directx', but this won't work. iOS as well as Android both support OpenGL ES only, which is a more lightweight version of the desktop OpenGL.
- The more frames you display, the more work the GPU has to do, the more battery your game drains.
- If you're playing on a tablet or phone, you typically don't have a charging adapter attached and you don't want your battery running low early just by playing a game (even if it's lots of fun).
- Don't tie your game logic or gameplay to any kind of fixed fps. If you have to, create fixed timesteps with n updates per minute, but don't directly link it to your display fps.
- With that in mind, I wouldn't try to go above 30 fps with any game. The less animations happening, the more you can save on this. For example, a card game or round-based strategy game could slow down to almost no updates (like 1 or 2 fps) unless there are animations happening.
- If you really think that having high fps is an important feature of your game (e.g. for faster effects and the like), allow the user to pick whether they'd like to experience the game with 60 fps or save battery life while still being able to play the game.

Comment: Thank you for this indepth answer! I think ill stick to the 30 fps because I want to conserve battery lol.